# Почему при тестировании выдает TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable?

Tags: python, юнит-тесты

При тестировании функции, которая считает количество конечных нулей факториала, выдает ошибку:
`TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable` 
В функции идет проверка, является ли аргумент целым числом, если нет, то вызываем ошибку `raise ValueError`
Сама функция:

```
def zeros(n: int) -> int:
    number_of_zeros: int = 0
    try:
        if n > 0 and n % int(n) == 0:        
            counter: int = int(math.log(n, 5))
            for i in range(1, counter + 1):
                number_of_zeros += int(n/(5 ** i))
            return number_of_zeros
        elif n == 0:
            return 0
        else:
            print(f'{n} must be a positive integer!!')
            raise ValueError
    except ValueError as error:
        print(error)
```

Тест этой функции:

```
class FatorialTestCase(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_argument_less_zero(self):
        result = zeros(-5)
        self.assertRaises(ValueError, result)
```

Как лучше всего вызывать ошибку при отрицательном значении, чтобы мы могли это нормально тестировать?

Comment: Просто убрать обработку ошибки в самой функции (убрать try-except)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Тут у вас две проблемы.

Во-первых, вы неправильно используете `assertRaises`. Вторым аргументом эта функция ожидает функцию, которую она вызовет и будет проверять, бросит ли такой вызов исключение того, типа что передан в первом параметре.

Вы же передаете не функцию, а результат вызова функции. Если бы функция `zeros` для отрицательного аргумента бросила бы ислючение, то выполнение до `assertRaises` вообще не дошло. `zeros` сейчас работает неправильно и исключения не бросает - это вторая проблема.

Сейчас же результатом работы функции является `None`, `assertRaises` пробует использовать его как функцию и ожидаемо не может - ошибка об этом и говорит `'NoneType' object is not callable`.

Нужно делать так:

```
def test_argument_less_zero(self):
    self.assertRaises(ValueError, zeros, -5)
```

А еще лучше и удобней использовать `assertRaises` как контекстный менеджер:

```
def test_argument_less_zero(self):
    with self.assertRaises(ValueError):
         zeros(-5)
```

Ну и конечно нужно исправить саму функцию, чтоб она таки бросала исключение, если агрумент отрицательный.